# How to find minutes from Date & Time in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 4 columns in my table RUNNING_INFO

```
TRAIN_START_DATE  VARCHAR2(8)
SCHEDULED_DATE VARCHAR2(8)
ACTUAL_DATE    VARCHAR2(8)
SCHEDULED_TIME VARCHAR2(8)
ACTUAL_TIME    VARCHAR2(8)
```

I have to extract the minutes from Actual/Scheduled Date & time , I have written following code for this

```
SELECT TRAIN_START_DATE,SCHEDULED_DATE,ACTUAL_DATE,SCHEDULED_TIME,ACTUAL_TIME,
CEIL((TO_DATE(concat(ACTUAL_DATE, ACTUAL_TIME) , 'DD-Mon-YYYYHH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(TRAIN_START_DATE, 'DD-Mon-YYYY'))*1440) as ACTUAL_MINS ,
CEIL((TO_DATE(concat(SCHEDULED_DATE, SCHEDULED_TIME) , 'DD-Mon-YYYYHH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(TRAIN_START_DATE, 'DD-Mon-YYYY'))*1440) as SCH_MINS FROM RUNNING_INFO
```

But I am not getting correct values in ACTUAL_MINS and SCH_MINS , for instance for the following rowset of Output , values are coming incorrectly in minutes :
Please guide how to find minutes correctly .

[image]

Comment: What values do you want?

Comment: for first row , actual minutes are coming 1449, it should be 1440+8 =1448 right ,similarly can be verified for other rows

Comment: Your data design is _fatally flawed._   You should never, ever, store a date as anything but DATE.  And the DATE data type _includes_ time, down to the second, so there is no need at all for your SCHEDULED_TIME and ACTUAL_TIME columns.  I would write up a sample solution as an answer, but I don't understand what 'actual minutes' actually represents.  But I'm absolutely certain of two things.  First, if you fix your data model, your solution will become trivial. Second, if you do not fix your data model, it's only a matter of time before you are back here with format errors.

Comment: Data Model can't be changed

Comment: @radha . . . Subtract 1.

Answer (score 1):

minutes between two dates where those dates *include* the time is

```
( date1 - date2 ) * 1440
```

in your case, where the date/time is separated into two columns, you can merge them become a date, so something like

```
to_date(to_char(sched_date,'yyyymmdd')||sched_time,'yyyymmddhh24:mi:ss')
```

for each date before doing the subtraction. And then you do not need CEIL because floating point will round up even the tiniest decimal

```
SQL> with t as
  2  (
  3  select
  4    '04-sep-2020' x1,
  5    '22:02:00' x2,
  6    '05-sep-2020' x3,
  7    '00:08:00'  x4
  8  from dual
  9  )
 10  SELECT
 11  CEIL((TO_DATE(concat(x1, x2) , 'DD-Mon-YYYYHH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(x3, 'DD-Mon-YYYY'))*1440) as ACTUAL_MINS ,
 12  CEIL((TO_DATE(concat(x3, x4) , 'DD-Mon-YYYYHH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(x1, 'DD-Mon-YYYY'))*1440) as SCH_MINS
 13  FROM t;

ACTUAL_MINS   SCH_MINS
----------- ----------
       -118       1449

SQL>
SQL> with t as
  2  (
  3  select
  4    '04-sep-2020' x1,
  5    '22:02:00' x2,
  6    '05-sep-2020' x3,
  7    '00:08:00'  x4
  8  from dual
  9  )
 10  SELECT
 11  (TO_DATE(concat(x1, x2) , 'DD-Mon-YYYYHH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(x3, 'DD-Mon-YYYY'))*1440 as ACTUAL_MINS ,
 12  (TO_DATE(concat(x3, x4) , 'DD-Mon-YYYYHH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(x1, 'DD-Mon-YYYY'))*1440 as SCH_MINS
 13  FROM t;

ACTUAL_MINS   SCH_MINS
----------- ----------
       -118       1448

SQL>
```

Comment: My apologies, I misread your initial question.  I've updated the answer